# How to display sub DataGridView on Cell Click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Hello All I work with cashier screen for Selling I want as the picture below. How to display sub DataGridView on Cell Click to choose an item
Please help me

[image]

Comment: why not open a dialog window with the grid?

Comment: So you're looking for a multi column drop down list/combo?

Comment: How can I do this? nbk

Comment: There is a CellClick event you can use. If you want to open a new window as suggested, you can create a new Grid form for your new DataGridView, declare `Dim gridForm = New Grid()` and on a new line do `gridForm.ShowDialog()` to open the form